# How to display popup on mouse over in html using JS and CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried to display a pop-up text on mouseover, based on elements and attributes. But, I want to display the content of `id` in the pop-up box on mouseover `<a>` on the text.

#### `html-1.xhtml`

```
<section id="sec1">
<div id="div1">
<p id="p1"><a class="keyword" id="k1" href="glossary.xhtml#g1">Lorem Ipsum</a> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
<p id="p2"><a class="keyword" id="k2" href="glossary.xhtml#g2">Aldus PageMaker</a> was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like <a class="keyword" id="k2" href="glossary.xhtml#g2">Aldus PageMaker</a> including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
<section>
```

#### `html-2.xhtml`

```
<section id="sec2">
<div id="div2">
<p id="p3">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
<p id="p4">It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
<section>
```

#### `Gloss.xhtml`

```
<section class="glossary"><header><h1 class="title">Glossary</h1></header>
<dl class="glossentrylist" id="g1"><dt class="glossterm" id="t1"><dfn>Lorem Ipsum</dfn></dt><dd class="glossdef" id="d1"><p id="gtd1">Lorem Ipsum.</p></dd></dl>
<dl class="glossentrylist" id="g2"><dt class="glossterm" id="t2"><dfn>Aldus PageMaker</dfn></dt><dd class="glossdef" id="d2"><p id="gtd1">Aldus PageMaker.</p></dd></dl>
</section>
```

It will be really very helpful, if someone help me to solve this.

Comment: Where is your JS code?

Answer (score 2):

If i understand correctly, you can do this purely with css. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrfn64cv/)

```css
p.ppup {border-bottom: thin dotted; background: #ffeedd;}
p.ppup:hover {text-decoration: none; background: #ffffff; z-index: 6; }
p.ppup span {position: absolute; left: -9999px;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0px; padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  border-style:solid; border-color:black; border-width:1px; z-index: 6;}
p.ppup:hover span {left: 2%; background: #ffffff;} 
p.ppup span {position: absolute; left: -9999px;
  margin: 4px 0 0 0px; padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px; 
  border-style:solid; border-color:black; border-width:1px;}
p.ppup:hover span {margin: 20px 0 0 170px; background: #ffffff; z-index:6;}
```

```html
<section id="sec1">
<div id="div1">
<p id="p1" class="ppup"><a class="keyword" id="k1" href="glossary.xhtml#g1">Lorem Ipsum</a><span> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</span></p>
<p id="p2" class="ppup"><a class="keyword" id="k2" href="glossary.xhtml#g2">Aldus PageMaker</a><span> was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like <a class="keyword" id="k2" href="glossary.xhtml#g2">Aldus PageMaker</a> including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span></p>
</div>
<section>
```

Comment: if you want it to display inline instead of under then just add display:inline; to the span and change the left to 170 in the ppup:hover http://jsfiddle.net/yrfn64cv/1/

Comment: Thank you very much @Rachel Gallen, Glossary keywords should show the corresponding definition, when mouse over on the keyword. And also glossary keywords and definitions are separated xhtml file. it should be displayed like http://jsfiddle.net/zq2btptb/

Comment: @Dari ah i didn't understand that but i hope i helped you solve it